# Why is the state still null even after setting it?

Tags: reactjs, esri

I'm trying to set an object then use it immediately but it is saying that it's null. I can observe in debug mode that the instantiated object is not null.

I could just use the instantiated objected instead of the constant but I was advised not to.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { loadModules } from "@esri/react-arcgis";

const TestLayer = props => {
  const [layer, setLayer] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    loadModules(["esri/layers/GraphicsLayer"])
      .then(([GraphicsLayer]) => {
        const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        setLayer(graphicsLayer);
        props.map.layers.add(layer); //layer is still null
      });
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default TestLayer;
```

Comment: I don't know much of react. But is `setLayer()` async function? And is it setting the layer on the `props` object?

Comment: It is async I believe. I'm adapting this example to mine https://github.com/Esri/react-arcgis

Comment: why you're loading your module inside of a function?

Comment: I'm adapting the BermudaTriangle example.

Comment: `props.map.layers.add(layer);` doesn't do anything with props and you're not supposed to mutate props so that's a good thing. Maybe just do setLayer and do a useMemo on layer to set new props when layer is not null.

Comment: I'll have to look into useMemo. That's a new concept to me

Comment: @HMR it isn't clear that the `add` method mutates props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's async like the comments suggest. The good news is that where you're trying to access it synchronously is the same place that you have access to the original object, so you can just use it directly:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { loadModules } from "@esri/react-arcgis";

const TestLayer = props => {
  const [layer, setLayer] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    loadModules(["esri/layers/GraphicsLayer"]).then(([GraphicsLayer]) => {
      const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
      setLayer(graphicsLayer);
      props.map.layers.add(graphicsLayer); // Don't need to access state here
    });
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default TestLayer;
```

Comment: Looking over the example again, this is exactly what they did. Sorry, React is still new to me.