# null is returned when fetching the api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I want to generate a page of items fetched from the api, each item has an id. If you click on one of those items, a page is being generated based on the template and item's id, so I need to pass id to the template. I managed to create the page with items, however when I try to generate an item page the fetch doesn't make any requests at all, thus resulting with null.
I tested this endpoint in swagger and it works perfectly.

App.tsx:

```
<Route path='/products/honey/:id' element={<Honey />} />
```

A page with items:

```
{items.map((item) => (
       <Link
         to={`/products/honey/${item.id}`}
         style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
        >
        <div>
         <div key={item.id} className={styles.item}>
         <img src={item.img_url} />
         <h1>{item.item_name}</h1>
         <h3>{item.price} руб.</h3>
         <button>В корзину</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </Link>
))}
```

Item template page:

```
const {id} = useParams<{id: string}>();
const [error, setError] = useState(null)
const [result, setResult] = useState(null)
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)
const [item, setItem] = useState<item | null>(null);
useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8000/items/by_id/${id}`)
            .then((res) =>
                res.json()
            )
            .then(
                data => {
                    setResult(data)
                    setItem(data)
                    console.log(item)
                },
                (error) => {
                    setIsLoaded(true)
                    setError(error)
                }
            )

    }, [id])
```

I tried to change localhost in URL to my docker container's name, but it doesn't matter as page with items works just fine with this URL. CORS can't be an issue either as page with items loads just fine.

Comment: When you say that null is being returned, do you mean that the console.log(item) is printing out null? Also, not directly related to the question, but is there a reason why you need both setResult and setItem if they are being updated the same way, as least in the code snippet here?

Comment: Also I'm having a little trouble understanding the structure of the endpoints in your application.. From what I understand, you have a page displaying various products, and from there you can click on a product to go to that product's page? If so I would expect the "page with items" to have an endpoint like "<BASE URL>/products" and the item page endpoint as "<BASE URL>/products/<productID>".

Comment: Yes, item is being printed as null as I can't see the request in the docker. I needed setResult to see what I am actually receiving just before I realized that there is no request, I can delete it. I don't think that react endpoints are the issue here as page is being loaded and I can see page id in the logs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the state still null even after setting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042984/why-is-the-state-still-null-even-after-setting-it)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve it by changing the endpoint in my backend
from

```
/items/by_id/{id}
```

to

```
/products/{id}
```